# Удаление файлов c#

Tags: c#, файлы

Не могу понять почему не удаляется файл, вроде и путь и имя указаны верно а все равно лежит в папке как лежал.

```
private void Main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"materials\");
    string delNAME = OrderData.deletFiles[0].ToString() + ".jpg";
    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        if (file.Name == delNAME)
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

может в коде где ошибся?

Comment: Директория текущая не совпадает. Она не всегда директория проекта! Используйте полный путь.

Comment: программа будет работать на нескольких пк. полный путь использовать не получиться

Comment: Тогда, чтобы узнать текущий каталог приложения используйте `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Comment: в качестве параметра G‌​etExecutingAssembly(‌​) указывать название приложения?я не знаком с этим методом, как его использовать ?

Comment: и да, директория правильная - в отладке видно что file.Name совпадает с delNAME

Comment: То, что я Вам написал возвращает String, в котором полный путь до приложения. Вставьте к себе в проект и посмотрите под дебагом.

Comment: Сделайте логирование file.Name. Как вариант - приведите к одному регистру.

Comment: Директория и так изначально правильная. del.Name == file.Name

Comment: Exception'а никакого нет? Я бы проверил права на файл

Comment: файл занят другим приложением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С кодом все в порядке, приложение не может получить доступ к файлу тк файл используется другим приложением.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    String currentDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.G‌​etExecutingAssembly(‌​).Location);
    String dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDir, "materials");
    System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, OrderData.deletFiles[0].ToString() + ".jpg"));
}
```

Comment: G‌​etExecutingAssembly(‌​) //  Недопустимый символ.

Comment: [GetExecutingAssembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не работает. Файл по прежнему на месте

Comment: Значит он чем-то занят, например открыт на чтение.

Comment: Ой, ну да, ошибся немного. в последней строке было конечно же не currentDir

Comment: Проверил Exeption, вы правы файл используется другим приложением. К сожалению это приложение мое. Но тут есть нюанс - картинка которую нужно удалить запускается на одной форме а удаляется когда эта форма закрыта уже.

Comment: Как Вы подгружаете картинку? Возможно Вы сами забываете закрыть файл. Предлагаю закрыть этот вопрос и создать новый с соответствующей проблемой

Comment: согласен с вами

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649584/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5