# Удаление файлов ранее загруженных в приложение

Tags: c#, файлы

Приветствую. Ситуация такая : есть несколько форм, на одну из форм динамически подгружаются картинки с тканями. в процессе работы можно удалить одну из картинок. реализовано это так - если нажать на картинку вылетит новая форма с той же картинкой большего размера и кнопкой удалить. при нажатии на нее имя картинки заносится в отдельный класс а при закрытии формы подгружается в `Main_FormClosed`. Код :

```
try
{
    string CompletePatchToEXE = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(CompletePatchToEXE + @"\\materials\\");
    string delNAME = OrderData.deletFiles[0].ToString() + ".jpg"; 

    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        if (file.Name == delNAME) 
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
}
```

А проблема в том, что указанный файл все еще используется приложением и удалить его оно не может. Как быть, подскажите? Спасибо.

Файлы картинок динамически загружаются из директории @"materials/" и присваиваются как фоновые изображения для пикчеров вот так:

```
PB.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("materials/" + ListName[i] + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Нужно использовать using при работе с файлом. Не блокировать файл на продолжительный момент. Можно написать две-три попытки удалить файл задействав ILDE и ожидание в 1 сек. Можно процедуры чтения вынести в static-методы и задействовать lock что б избежать "многозадачных" конфликтов.

Comment: можно подробнее про using ? какую строку обернуть?

Comment: Строку где вы читаете файл. Например `using ( File f = File.Open()) {};`

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли. файлы картинок динамически загружаются из директории @"materials/" и присваиваются как фоновые изображения для пикчеров вот так :  PB.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("materials/" + ListName[i] + ".jpg");

Comment: странно, но вчера все удалялось без проблем

Comment: тогда вынесете удаление и загрузку в static методы.

Comment: если вынести в static метод удаления выведет ошибку : Доступ к члену Main.Main_FormClosed (///) через ссылку на экземпляр невозможен;

Comment: вот так `static void DoDeleteFiles() { try {  ....  file.Delete } } ` и так `static Image DoLoadImage(string filename) { return Image.FromFile(filename); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В комментарии у вас написано:

```
PB.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("materials/" + ListName[i] + ".jpg");
```

Изображение загружается и присваивается свойству BackgroundImage. Здесь-то и удерживается его хендл. Чтобы изображение можно было удалить, нужно освободить его хендл.

Например, это можно сделать так:

```
Image imageCopy;

using (var imageSource = Image.FromFile("materials/" + ListName[i] + ".jpg")
    imageCopy = new Bitmap(imageSource);

PB.BackgroundImage = imageCopy;
```

В данном коде создаётся копия изображения - его хендл не будет привязан к файлу. А при выходе из блока `using` будет вызван метод `Dispose`, который освободит ресурс - файл оригинального изображения. После чего его можно удалять.

P.S. Само удаление выполняется одной строкой:

```
new FileInfo(delNAME).Delete();
```

Цикл не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо. все заработало